# Is the phrase Abracadabra found in any Hebrew literature?

Tags: etymology

I recently learned that Abracadbra is a Hebrew word from אברא כדברא, so I was wondering if this phrase appears anywhere in the Gemara or midrash

Comment: It being Hebrew or Aramaic is folk-etymology. No one really knows the origin of the phrase and it is not attested to in classical Jewish sources.

Comment: and see https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%90%D7%91%D7%A8%D7%A7%D7%93%D7%91%D7%A8%D7%94

Comment: @Deuteronomy Ah I was just thinking maybe it was used in some midrash about Creation or something

Comment: I remember seeing it once. This is going to drive me crazy :)